# Detect browser out of focus

Tags: javascript, focus, visibility

I want to detect when the browser goes out of focus. More specifically, here is my case:

I have my page opened and when I change the tab, it can be detected using `visibilitychange`. But when I go to another app, ex: VS Code without specifically minimizing the browser window or changing the tab, it does not work.

Here is a representation:

- A->my current tab where I want the change to be detected.
- I go to tab B, the change is detected.
- I come back to A and then without minimising the browser, I go to VS Code the change is not detected.
- I go back to tab A, then to tab B and then go to VSCode, the change gets detected.

Comment: Your other app's window must not necessarily cover the browser window, they could both still be visible. If the API reported the page as _invisible_ in that state, it would simply be wrong. (And I don't think it should be the job of an in-browser API, to check on whatever else might be going on on my desktop.)

Comment: Possibly the same question, but it's unclear if things have moved on - the jquery solution seems to still work, but this question not tagged jquery and perhaps a bit of overkill to add it just for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: @freedomn-m using angular for the project, so don't want to add jquery over it.

Comment: @CBroe the thing is I want to detect whether browser is now in focus, I guess chrome allows it through its own api, but that would mean I would have to detect it for specific browsers. I wanted to see if there is any single solution for it. Haven't been able to find any till now.

Comment: There are other solutions in that question